# Spring externalContext.redirect when ProxyPass, ProxyPassReverse

Tags: apache, web, tomcat, jsf-2, virtualhost

I have one httpd with ssl and a virtual host on it and a tomcat with my app, when someone connect to my domain, [www.mydomian.com](http://www.mydomian.com), he can see my app [www.mydomain.com:8080/myapp](http://www.mydomain.com:8080/myapp), this is working fine.

But in the app the user fill a form and after this form redirect him to a greetings page, thanks.xhtml, but instead of this the user is redirected to ssl site mydomain.com/myapp/index.xhtml, i tested in the tomcat manager using the link and the app works fine, what i am doing wrong?

I am using this virtual host directives

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

This is my redirection in the app

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
externalContext.redirect("../thanks.xhtml");
```

Comment: Try using an absolute path (`/thanks.xhtml`) in your redirect. It will be appended to your applications URL `http://example.com/myapp`.

Comment: now send me to mydomain.com/myapp/index.xhtml not executing the redirection, and that location doesn't exit the real path is mydomain.com/index.xhtml, what i am doing wrong?